# Try to add RecycleView to SDK 25

Tags: java, android

I try to create a new project then add RecycleView like in my book.
But in my case, AndroidStudio give an error after add this library:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(25.3.1) from [com.android.support:design:25.3.1] AndroidManifest.xml:27:9-31
    is also present at [com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.0-alpha1] AndroidManifest.xml:24:9-38 value=(26.0.0-alpha1).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to <meta-data> element at AndroidManifest.xml:25:5-27:34 to override.
```

I can't fix it, my book with this app don't contain solution :(
This book describe apps in Android 6, but i also choose Android 6 at the beginning.

Comment: Make sure all support library entries you have in your build.gradle are the same version.

Comment: have you added dependencies in build,gradle

Comment: i change RecycleView to 25.0.0 and works, but it is good solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try like this**, this may help

```
dependencies {
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1"
    compile "com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:25.3.1"
    compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1"
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1"
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.0.0'
}
```

Comment: i change RecycleView to 25.0.0 and it is fine now, thanks

Comment: happy coding man